# Mac OS X / RSS Growl Notifications

Tags: macos, rss

Is there a good program for a "real-time" RSS Growl notifications? I would like to install a Growl alert for RSS feeds. When a channel publishes RSS changes, I want to see an alert.

I tried OmniGrowl but I had problems with it on my new MacBook Pro.

Thx!

Answer (score 4):

NetNewsFeed does growl notifications and it's free now.

Answer (score 4):

did you try http://osiris.laya.com/projects/RSSGrowler/ yet?

Answer (score 4):

Check out [NetNewsWire](http://www.newsgator.com/INDIVIDUALS/NETNEWSWIRE/).